# Node file uploads and sychronicity

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

While I'm generally comfortable with rudimentary asynch patterns in node I have come across a situation where I need the return value from an asynch call in a generally synchronous situation.

Given the function:

```
modelHelper.saveFile = function(field) {
 var url = cloudinary.uploader.upload(this.req.files[field.name].path, function(result) {
     if(typeof result.url != "undefined" && result.url.length > 0) 
         {
            console.log(" \n\n\n Inside the cloudinary call.");
            console.log("\n\n URL = " + result.url);
            return result.url;
         }
     return false;
 });

 console.log("\n\n\n Outside the load, URL =" + url);

 if(!url) return "";
 return url;
};
```

This function is called in the case of uploading a file to a server, and is called by a simple loop which loops over all of the elements of a page.  For the majority of cases it's a simple mapping of variable to value, as such I really don't want to need to inject a `next` into this function.

Here's the caller:

```
modelHelper.parseField = function(field) {
var type = field.type;

switch(type) {
case "email":
case "url":
    return strings.exists(this.param(field.name)) ?
            this.param(field.name) : "";
    break;
case "file": 
    return modelHelper.resolveFile.bind(this)(field);
    break;
default: 
    return strings.exists(this.param(field.name)) ?
            strings.makeSafe(this.param(field.name)) : "";
}
```

and this, in turn is  called by:

```
modelHelper.populate = function(elements, record, next){
var len = elements.length;
parseField = modelHelper.parseField.bind(this);
while(len--)
    if((elements[len]["type"] != "captcha")) 
        this[record][elements[len]['name']] = parseField(elements[len]); 

next.bind(this)();
};
```

as such, I'm looking for a pattern that will block execution until the file operation in saveFile returns a variable;  something like wrapping it in a setInterval type call was my first thought, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Pass a `callback` to `saveFile` and call it with the url once the upload is complete

```
 modelHelper.saveFile = function(field, callback) {
  var url = cloudinary.uploader.upload(this.req.files[field.name].path, function(result) {
    if(typeof result.url != "undefined" && result.url.length > 0) {
        console.log(" \n\n\n Inside the cloudinary call.");
        console.log("\n\n URL = " + result.url);
        return callback(null, result.url);
    }
    return callback();
  });
};
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that changing the name of the called function from "next" to "callback" will not address the underlying architectural challenge.  The point is that there is no sensible callback to pass in this context as we cannot guarentee when the saveFile will be called (inside the context of an unpredictable sequence of elements).   Short of hearing a better answer to the original question I've accepted that an architecture change is required and I'm pushing all of the checks into an array of promises and using Q to run that array as a chain.  Haven't tested it yet, but it should work.